# Prevent iPad screen for turning off when not in horizontal orientation

Tags: ipad, screen, screen-lock

Is there a way to prevent iPad from going into Sleep mode when not in horizontal mode?

Comment: Is there a particular app or function that you are needing to stay awake? Are you wanting to prevent it from sleeping altogether?

Comment: @drivec Yes, one particular application is the default pdf viewer of the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent iPad from automatically going into sleep mode, by setting **Auto Lock** to **Never**. But this setting cannot be made dependant on the current orientation of the device.

To set Auto Lock to Never, go to Settings App → Display & Brightness → Auto Lock and set it to **Never**. iPad can be send into Sleep mode anytime by manually pressing the physical Power button.